# Can you call an external Javascript with an onblur event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onchange, onblur

I have written a JavaScript script and saved it as an external file, and now want to call it to validate a form entry (not the whole form) when they finish.  I was thinking of using `onchange` and `onblur`, but can't find any way to do this.  Am I just being blind?

Comment: Show the code you tried, there could be some mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to include the external script in your HTML page as well.  Assuming your external script file is named `my_external.js` and contains a function named `my_external_function`, the following code sample should work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="my_external.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" onblur="my_external_function()" />
</body>
</html>
```